# IntelliJ splits my code when reformatting using ctrl+alt+L

Tags: intellij-idea

ctrl+alt+L splits my code like this:

```
public void message_should_be_displayed(String text) {
    qip.executeAssertEquals("Asserting if correct alert msg is displayed : ", text, qip.driver.switchTo()
            .alert()
            .getText());
}
```

It puts the last 2 lines in separate lines if I do reformat. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: i never said it was broken. i said that after reformatting the the last 2 commands get moved to separate lines. i'd prefer they didn't. hopefully there is way to avoid this.

Comment: Can you specify what plugins you are using and if you use a linting tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Chained method calls: Do not wrap.